# Prime numbers number theory

Tags: number-theory

I need to prove that if $m \geq 2$ and not divisible by any prime $p$, with $p \leq \sqrt{m}$ then $m$ is prime.

I tried to use the contrapositive but I got stuck.

Also I need to use this, to show that all number $n^2-n+41$ are prime for $n\leq40$. 
Many thanks

Comment: Marcus, thanks for editing my question, I am not sure how to use the math edit in here.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to prove that if $m$ is not prime, it has a non-trivial (i.e. $\ne 0, 1$) divisor $\le \sqrt m$.

Indeed, let $a$ be a divisor of $m$. If $a \le \sqrt m$, there's nothing to prove. If $a > \sqrt m$, then $$b = \frac ma < \frac m{\sqrt m} = \sqrt m.$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that positive $m$ has a divisor $d$ greater than $\sqrt{m}$ but less than $m$. Then $d' = \frac{m}{d}$ is also a divisor of $m$. But since $d > \sqrt{m}$, this other divisor $d'$ must be less than $\sqrt{m}$.

For this reason, if after dividing $m$ by all primes $p \leq \sqrt{m}$ you have not found a single one that is a divisor of $m$, then it is unnecessary to try any of the primes greater than $\sqrt{m}$.

As for the second part of your question, regarding $n^2 - n + 41$, I have only a dim, vague idea of how the result about $\sqrt{m}$ might be relevant. I wish I could tell you something more clever than just testing each $0 < n < 41$.